# How to debug a node app from WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, node-inspector

I am running `node --inspect app.js` inside of a docker container.
In the console I see `Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/0b4d64ac-90c1-480d-a98a-7061c0b49189`

How can I debug using WebStorm? I know on a previous version of node there was `--debug` I would then connect using the Node.js Remote Debugger.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html -- and a blog post too: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/ (Updated on October 20, 2017)

Answer (score 0):

To attach to remote Node.js app started with `--inspect`/`--inspect-brk`, (Node.js 7+), you need using [Chromium Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-chromium-remote.htmlt) run configuration.

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#node_docker_run_debug